# Zend autoloader

Tags: php, html, zend-framework, autoloader

I am trying to autoload the forms found in my project under application/forms/*.php ( in this case, LoginForm.php ).

How do I configure Zends autoloader to load this form automatically? As I don't want to use ugly namespaces I am enabling the fallback in my bootstrap. I haven't got anything related to forms configured in my application.ini

thanks!

Comment: http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.loader.autoloader-resource.html

Comment: @AlisterBulman oh yeah didn't find that through google.., no doesn't answer my question.

Comment: Give more details, what kind of namespace would you like. Anything can be configured. By default you should be able to access that form by naming the class `[Appnamespace_]Form_LoginForm`. Appnamespace you can configure in application.ini

Comment: If you are using Zend_Application, then the autoloader is already set up in which case you should follow namesnik's suggestion of naming `Appnamespace_Form_LoginForm`.

Comment: @drew010 its what Iam trying to avoid, I prefer being able to call new LoginForm without the namespace prefixes ( currently doing that as well with my models! ) . My apps namespace is Application and when calling Application_Form_LoginForm it also fails. The dir structure is: application -> forms -> LoginForm.php

Comment: Antwan: Think of it differently. It shouldn't be called 'LoginForm', it should be called 'Appname_Form_Login' -- this is the logic Zend is using. If you want to use 'LoginForm' you need to think about interoperability; is this going to be a fully generic LoginForm? If not, why is it going to have a fully generic name? What about later on if there is another login form?

Comment: To expand on RiverC's great comment, if you have no hierarchy in your class names, the autoloader will have to do a lot of inefficient work to find the class to autoload.  How will it know what directory LoginForm is in without first looking in a huge number of places?  I'm not sure why calling `Application_Form_LoginForm` fails, as that should work given your directory structure.

Comment: Which version of ZendFramework?

Comment: 1.11.1 -- latest version, downloaded it a few days ago

Comment: @AntwanvanHoudt see new answer - I'm not 100% sure I've understood your question correctly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The default autoloader will load this for you. Make sure that you have checked the following:-

1. Your file is application/forms/Loginform.php
2. The file contains something like this:-

   ```
   class Application_Form_Loginform extends Zend_Form
   {
      //Take special note of the capitalisation - it is important
      // Also note it is Form NOT Forms
       public function init()
       {
           //Your code here
       }
   }
   ```
3. Call your class like this:-

   ```
   $form = new Application_Form_Loginform();
   ```

Take extra care over letter case, it is important that you get it exactly right or the autoloader will not find you class and will complain.

Comment: I actually started doing it like this, though it originally isn't what I wanted. Thanks for the answer in any case.

Comment: You get used to the naming convention. I didn't like it too much at first, but it has grown on me.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answers your question, as its a little vague, but try the following.

In your bootstrap:

```
protected function _initAppAutoload()
{
    $moduleLoad = new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array(
       'namespace' => '',
       'basePath'   => APPLICATION_PATH
    ));
}
```

Obviously then the Form_LoginForm() class would exist in application/forms/LoginForm.php